# Angular reactive form: Displaying error text when form has error

Tags: angular, forms, conditional-statements, rendering, reactive

I´m struggling with displaying error message under the textarea in my form. I have custom-textarea which is a normal texarea component with some handy attributes. One of them is helper text which is displayed below the textarea box. I find the logic of my conditional rendering okay, although it is not being displayed on the screen when the specific error occurs. Hardcoded value for my helper text works, so there is no problem with the text being displayed. Do you have any idea what could be the problem here?

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editComment()">
    <custom-textarea
      formControlName="text"
      helper-text="{{!editForm.valid ? ((editForm.controls.text.errors?.['required'] ? 'Text for the comment is required!' : null) || (editForm.controls.text.errors?.['minlength'] ? 'Minimal length of text is 3 characters!' : null)) : null}}"
    ></custom-textarea>
</form>
```

```
export class EditCommentComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() comment: Comment;
editForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      text: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
    });
}

ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.editForm.controls.text.setValue(this.comment.text);
  }
```

Comment: With the edit you did, it's working for me (with a simple textarea and a span). Are you sure to listen your `helper-text` changes in your text-area component ?

Comment: Yes, when I hardcode some value ```helper-text="some text"``` it displays the text under the textarea :/

Comment: Can we have the code of your `custom-textarea` component ?

Comment: There is no code available, I´m just using the component as some kind of a plugin component library, but thank you for your willingness to help. Originally I thought the error has something to do with the way I wrote the conditional rendering, but I guess it is the component

Comment: Have you tried to use `[helper-text] = "!editForm.valid ? ((editForm.controls.text.errors?.['required'] ? 'Text for the comment is required!' : null) || (editForm.controls.text.errors?.['minlength'] ? 'Minimal length of text is 3 characters!' : null)) : null"` ?

Comment: Thank you so much @archelite! This is working!

Comment: I made an answer of my comment, it will be more visible and you can check it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property binding for helper-text. Change :

```
helper-text="{{!editForm.valid ? ((editForm.controls.text.errors?.['required'] ? 'Text for the comment is required!' : null) || (editForm.controls.text.errors?.['minlength'] ? 'Minimal length of text is 3 characters!' : null)) : null}}"
```

by :

```
[helper-text] = "!editForm.valid ? ((editForm.controls.text.errors?.['required'] ? 'Text for the comment is required!' : null) || (editForm.controls.text.errors?.['minlength'] ? 'Minimal length of text is 3 characters!' : null)) : null"
```

This way, `helper-text` property will no longer be static but dynamic (Check  [Angular Documentation  on Property Binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding))

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your .html file add this:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editComment()">
    <custom-textarea
      formControlName="text"
      helper-text="{{!editForm.valid ? ((editForm.controls.text.errors?.['required'] ? 'Text for the comment is required!' : null) || (editForm.controls.text.errors?.['minlength'] ? 'Minimal length of text is 3 characters!' : null)) : null}}"
    ></custom-textarea>
<span class="error invalid-feedback"
                  *ngIf="editForm.errors? && editForm.controls.text">Error in form</span>
</form>
```

I assume that you are using bootstrap and you can use this class "error invalid-feedback"

Comment: I don´t need the span tag since helper text attributes has this functionality to show the text as if it was span